# How can I export a PostgreSQL table to HTML?

Tags: postgresql

How can I save a PostgreSQL table to HTML?

Comment: This is a very general question.  What kind of HTML format are you looking for?  Do you have any particular programming language you want to use?

Answer (score 12):

I'll take a stab at assuming what you mean.  In psql:

```
dbname=# \H
dbname=# \d tablename
```

Comment: or possibly if you want the data, then \H followed by a select statement. The key point is that the \H command (or the -H or --html command line options) in psql turn on "html output mode".

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an XML "forest":

```
SELECT xmlforest (
  "FirstName" as "FName", "LastName" as "LName",
  ’string’ as "str", "Title", "Region" )
FROM "Demo"."demo"."Employees";
```

With some data in the employees table, this might result in:

```
<FName>Nancy</FName>
<LName>Davolio</LName>
<str>string</str>
<Title>Sales Representative</Title>
<Region>WA</Region>
...
<FName>Anne</FName>
<LName>Dodsworth</LName>
<str>string</str>
<Title>Sales Representative</Title>
```

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support

Comment: He said /HTML/, which is a significantly harder problem.